# Google Sheet script for keeping the first tab in view at all times?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a lot of tabs that I frequently scroll though, but I wish that the master sheet I have (the first tab) is always displayed at the bottom no matter where I'm at in the scrolling process. That way I can just quickly click on the master sheet's tab to go back to it.

I know there's not a way to do this in any of the settings, but perhaps there's an onOpen trigger I could put in a script?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing can control the tabs down below like that but I think you can script yourself to jump back to tab one from the menu

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Custom Menu')
      .addItem('Go To Tab 1', 'tab1')
      .addToUi();
}

function tab1(){
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ss = sh.getSheetByName("Tab2");
sh.setActiveSheet(ss);
SpreadsheetApp.flush();

}
```

should do the trick

Comment: That's not a bad workaround! Although it takes about the same amount of clicking/effort to just click "All Sheets" at the bottom and then click on the master sheet. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

It is quite simpler.

```
function firstSheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheet[0].activate();

}
```

getSheets() return an array with all sheets.

If you need to go to the first sheet, you only need to activate the one at position 0 in the array.